# Not Understanding C++ Memory Alignment

Tags: c++

I understand that in C++, if we have a struct like this:

```
struct x_
{
   char a;     // 1 byte
   int b;      // 4 bytes
   short c;    // 2 bytes
   char d;     // 1 byte
} MyStruct;
```

Memory structure will look like this due to compiler padding:

```
struct x_
{
   char a;            // 1 byte
   char _pad0[3];     // padding to put 'b' on 4-byte boundary
   int b;            // 4 bytes
   short c;          // 2 bytes
   char d;           // 1 byte
   char _pad1[1];    // padding to make sizeof(x_) multiple of 4
}
```

Can somebody please help me understand why sizeof(x_) must be a multiple of 4, and not any other number?

Comment: This is totally platform/compiler dependent. In this case it's most likely to ensure that memory addresses are aligned to multiples of 4, because reading more than 1 byte from an unaligned memory address is either less efficient or impossible.

Comment: Generally if you put the larger types at the beginning of the struct, you give the compiler more flexibility to minimize struct size and padding. Other than that, padding is completely implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

At least, a class must have the same alignment largest alignment of any of its non-static data member. So `x_` must be aligned as `b`. If `x_` had a lower alignment requirement, then `b` could be misaligned. Imagine an object `x_` at address 3 then its `b` member would also be at an address 3+alignof(int). If `alignof(int)==4` then `b` would be at address 7, so it would be misaligned. So following this example, `alignof(`x_`)==4`;

Then the size of an object must be a multiple of the alignment because elements of an array are required to be contiguous: a pointer to the end of element *n* must be a pointer to the element *n+1*. So in your case `x` size must be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Thanks @Oliv, this makes sense, but I've come across this information: "For simple data types, the compiler assigns addresses that are multiples of the size in bytes of the data type. Thus, the compiler assigns addresses to variables of type long that are multiples of four, setting the bottom two bits of the address to zero." from MS docs. But isn't long 8bytes? So then why multiples of 4?

Comment: link to this info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/alignment-cpp-declarations?view=vs-2019

Comment: try searching long and not longs, it comes up immediately. And please be nice, I am new to all this